# How do I format individual lines in a textbox via Microsoft PowerPoint macros?

Tags: vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-2013

I want a textbox where the first line and subsequent lines of text have different formatting, but they must be in the same textbox. This is what I currently have, which applies the same formatting to all text.

```
Sub geberateSlide() 
  ...
  With currSlide.Shapes.AddTextbox(Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
  Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=headerWidth, Height:=headerHeight)
    .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Test Box" & vbCrLf & "Description"
    .TextFrame.AutoSize = ppAutoSizeNone
    .Height = headerHeight
    .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0,0,0)
    .Line.Visible = True
  End With
...
End Sub
```

The text should be Arial 8. Line 1 should be black and bold, while subsequent text should be blue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.TextFrame.TextRange.Lines(0, 1)` will target the first line.

[image]

%300 Zoom

```
With currSlide.Shapes.AddTextbox(Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
                                 Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=headerWidth, Height:=headerHeight)
    .Height = headerHeight
    .TextFrame.AutoSize = ppAutoSizeNone
    With .TextFrame.TextRange
        .Text = "Test Box" & vbCrLf & "Description"
        With .Font
            .Color = vbBlue
            .Size = 8
            .Name = "Arial"
        End With

        With .Lines(1).Font
            .Color = vbBlack
            .Bold = msoTrue
        End With
    End With
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer! It was an interesting question.  I usually don't use PowerPoint but I have a general idea of the VBA model; so it wasn't too difficult to figure out.

Comment: Just a comment that 0 implies the entire paragraph for the legacy TextRange object. So you could get the same result with just .Lines(1)

Comment: Also, TextRange is legacy object so you need to use TextRange2 to access to the newer text styles.

Comment: @ShyamPillai Thanks I updated `.Lines(1).  I had trouble trying to implement `TextRange2`.  Maybe it is because for some reason my Office 360 runs in 32bit mode.  In any case,  `TextRange` is legacy but it is still supported.  `TextRange2` only works in Office 2013 and later and there is a lot of people still using Office 2007.

Comment: yes, TextRange can be used unless you want to format using the new styles. Also, TextRange2 was introduced in 2007 not 2013.